# Replacement for RequestPolicy addon for Firefox?

Tags: security, firefox, privacy

The venerable, vintage, and very useful, RequestPolicy add-on for Firefox now seems to be behaving erratically for me (and I know that I won't be able to use it for much longer in any case, when Firefox ESR moves to the next post-Quantum major release).

I am using RequestPolicy 0.5.28.1, and my Firefox ESR (on MacOS, if relevant) has recently updated to 52.8.1.

Now, RequestPolicy shows "Warning: Prefetch is enabled" in its menu, even though this does not appear to be the case in the RequestPolicy preferences. The "Disable prefetching" menu item takes you to a (not found) page on the RequestPolicy website.

In addition, the "Other origins within this page" submenu in RequestPolicy no longer opens.

RequestPolicy has served me very well, but it would appear that I now do definitely need to find a replacement addon.

I know that [RequestPolicy Continued](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/requestpolicy-continued/) is under development, but it also does not appear to be compatible with Firefox Quantum. (I also did not install it previously as: original RequestPolicy still worked for me, RP-C was in a beta state, and I found its changed interface rather confusing.)

Are there any other Firefox addons that do essentially the same thing, namely: block all content from loading from other domains (or subdomains) unless expressly permitted?

Comment: Really for *all* not-1st-party domains – or just "bad ones"? I use *uBlock Origin* which blocks all "suspicious domains" (going by filter lists) unless I explicitly enable them.

Comment: I think I would prefer something that works in as similar a way to RequestPolicy as possible: different people have different ideas as to what constitutes a trustworthy third-party site, and so, therefore, for me, "Deny all other than what I allow" is probably the best strategy.

Comment: I did have a look at uBlock Origin, but found it very confusing, with an interface with few tool-tips where it was unclear what everything does, and also not entirely clear how to make it work in a RequestPolicy-like way.

Comment: I've never used RequestPolicy, so I'm not familiar with that. Could well be you cannot make uBlock act exactly like that, at least not easily. So I drop out here: hopefully someone else can turn up with a solution. Good luck!

Comment: Just saw [First Party Isolation](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/first-party-isolation/). Would that go in the right direction?

Comment: First Party Isolation sounds interesting, but it is not entirely clear from its description what it does: it sounds like it may be an all-or-nothing (or rather, nothing-but-1st-party-or-all) approach? It also needs Firefox 58.0a1 or newer so I am unable to test it here just now (we only have Firefox ESR available).

Comment: I'm not using it, so I cannot tell. Just found [a German article](https://www.kuketz-blog.de/firefox-first-party-isolation-firefox-kompendium-teil4/) in Mike Kuketz' Firefox compendium introducing it. Maybe you could run that through some translator to give it a glance whether it fits your needs? As far as I understood, it puts each party in a separate container, and you could decide which to trust and "set free" (define exceptions).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the original RequestPolicy add-on has subsequently been repackaged by the RequestPolicy Continued developers (as RequestPolicy Legacy), and this now seems to be working acceptably for me at the present time.

(This is unfortunately not a long-term solution, as the repackaged add-on is also not compatible with Firefox Quantum, but it is a reasonable work-around for the time being.)

- [RequestPolicy Legacy](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/requestpolicy-legacy/)